# Logstash agent doesn't run as a daemon on MAC OS X 10.9.1

Tags: macos, mac, boot, daemon, plist

I need to run the logstash agent as a Daemon on an MAC OS X System whenever the system boots up

> terminal: **/usr/local/logstash/bin/logstash agent -f /usr/local/etc/cvlog.conf**

Per terminal the program is working succesfully but as an daemon it doesn't start.

**My com.bcd.logstash.plist**

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
<string>com.bcd.logstash</string>
<key>KeepAlive</key>

<dict>
<key>SuccessfulExit</key>
</false>
</dict>
<key>ProgramArguments</key> 
<array>
      <string>/usr/local/logstash/bin/logstash</string>
      <string>agent</string>
      <string>-f</string>
      <string>/usr/local/etc/cvlog.conf</string>
</array>
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
</true> 
</dict>
</plist>
```

I start with:

> launchtl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.bcd.logstash.plist

Syslog Error Message

> com.apple.launchd[1] (com.bcd.logstash[pid]): Exited with code:1
>
> com.apple.launchd[1] (com.bcd.logstash[pid]): Exited with code:143

What's wrong with my plist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem I see is a typo in the `ProgramArguments` key (you have an extra "m"). If fixing that doesn't make it work, I'd add something like:

```
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/tmp/logstash.out</string>
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/tmp/logstash.err</string>
```

...and see if those files tell you anything useful about what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the file logstash.out tells me what's going wrong :) My plist is ok and works. The ProgramArguments key i had only edit here ;). The problem was in my logstash config file. I had to be set a standard path/home variable (since_db) for my logs which i want to collect with logstash.